# Overriding environment variables per directory

Tags: bash, terminal

I haven't been able to find the answer to this anywhere and suspect it's not possible. I'd like to know if I can somehow override environment variables set by `export MY_VARIABLE="some-value"` per directory. Meaning, once I `cd` into a particular directory where x variable is overridden, anything being run from that directory would see the new value.

Is that possible without expicitly `export`ing? Perhaps adding some file to the directory like `.bashrc` or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: You could write a function to call `cd` for you; do you need something more sophisticated than that?

Comment: You could certainly do something with a local `.vars` or whatever file. You would just need to explicitly source that file as you `cd` around and they wouldn't be scoped to just within that directory (they would bleed-over to anywhere you `cd` afterwards unless you also handle `cd`-ing away and unset anything you just set).

Comment: There are scripts that do this -- `rvm` is one of them -- but it's an idea with security implications that should really make you think twice, unless you never work with source trees shared by people you don't trust, cd into directories made by unpacking tarballs from strangers, etc.

Comment: For example, imagine `cd`ing into a directory that sets `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to `rm -rf $HOME`

Comment: Yet, if you call your .env file something like .енв (env in cyrillic script) or .xyz it is far less likely somebody would be able to inject the malicious rm -rf ~ into your directory loading. Unless they know your setup and are intentionally targeting you which is probably not that likely.

Comment: Btw, you can find scripts that achieve what you wanted on [kde techbase](https://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/Environment#Useful_Bash_Scripts). Just pick and adjust what you like and that's it. For your need, findup script and cd() function from their .bashrc get the job done. Possibly change .build-config into something specific for you to circumvent the above mentioned malicious code injection. I've been using that code (or some previous version of it, I haven't checked) for like decades and it works like a charm.